# Circuit breaker design pattern implementation

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I have tried unsuccessfully to implement circuit breaker pattern, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_breaker_design_pattern), in Java using Spring framework.

How can you implement circuit breaker pattern by Java and Spring?

Comment: Please make body short. Show your commitment to your work and initial attempt. Ask clear question finally. Use appropriate tags.

Answer (score 20):

For a simple, straightforward [circuit breaker implementation](https://github.com/jhalterman/failsafe#circuit-breakers), check out [Failsafe](https://github.com/jhalterman/failsafe) (which I authored). Ex:

```
CircuitBreaker breaker = new CircuitBreaker()
  .withFailureThreshold(5)
  .withSuccessThreshold(3)
  .withDelay(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

Failsafe.with(breaker).run(() -> connect());
```

Doesn't get much simpler.

Comment: what you do in your fall back?

Answer (score 13):

[Apache commons](https://commons.apache.org/) has some implementations for several types of lightweight circuit breakers, here's [a link to the docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/concurrent/CircuitBreaker.html)

The project provides the `EventCountCircuitBreaker` and `ThresholdCircuitBreaker` classes, and an abstract `AbstractCircuitBreaker` so you could implement your own.

The code is open sources and is [hosted at github](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/tree/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/concurrent), so anyone attempting to implement the pattern should at least take a peek.

Answer (score 5):

[Spring cloud](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/) provides some interesting integration with [Hystrix](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix). You should probably have a look into it...

Comment: You should look at [Resilience4J](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs) instead of Hystrix, which has been deprecated ([source](https://www.infoq.com/articles/spring-cloud-hystrix/)).

Answer (score 4):

### Regarding the pattern itself

You can obtain a lot of useful information about this pattern at [Martin Fowler's blog](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html). It contains ruby implementation as well as references for implementation in other languages.

### Regarding the java spring implementation

Please check the [JRugged library](https://github.com/Comcast/jrugged).
It contains the Circuit Breaker implementation in spring as well as other design patterns.

Comment: Hi, Is there any concrete implementation of Circuit breaker for any web service using java and spring together.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I went through JRugged library, it is nice and however could see it as huge, but I need to attend a critical situation immediately using circuit breaker and hence looking for any simple spring solution. Please suggest and share

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need to be using Spring cloud or Spring boot to use Hystrix.
Using [hystrix-javanica](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/tree/master/hystrix-contrib/hystrix-javanica) makes it easy to use Hystrix with plain old Spring too.

Here is an example of fallback methods (both methods, getMessageTimeout and getMessageException, fail by default):

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class CircuitBreakingWithHystrix {

  @Bean
  public HystrixCommandAspect hystrixAspect() {
    return new HystrixCommandAspect();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    ApplicationContext ctx
      = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(CircuitBreakingWithHystrix.class);
    ExampleService ex = ctx.getBean(ExampleService.class);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      System.out.println(ex.getMessageException());
      System.out.println(ex.getMessageTimeout());
    }
  }

  @Service
  class ExampleService {

    /*
     * The default Hystrix timeout is 1 second. So the default 
     * version of this method will always fail.  
     * Adding the @HystrixProperty will cause 
     * the method to succeed.
     */
    @HystrixCommand(
      commandProperties = { 
      //@HystrixProperty(name = EXECUTION_ISOLATION_THREAD_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS,
      //                 value = "5000")
      },
      fallbackMethod = "messageFallback"
    )
    public String getMessageTimeout() {
      try {
        //Pause for 4 seconds
        Thread.sleep(4000);
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        // Do something clever with this
      }
      return "result";
    }

    @HystrixCommand(
      fallbackMethod = "messageFallback")
    public String getMessageException() {
      throw new RuntimeException("Bad things happened");
    }

    private String messageFallback(Throwable hre) {
      return "fallback";
    }

  }
```

You can also examine the throwable sent to the fallback method to identify why the method call failed.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at [JCircuitBreaker](http://secodo.net/projects/jcircuitbreaker/) . The implementation there implements circuit breaker like approach.

Please note that this is not 1:1 implementation of the pattern because it does not define fixed states like "half-open". Instead it makes the decision (if the breaker should be open or closed) basing on current application state (using so called "break strategy"). Nevertheless it should be possible to define such a "break strategy" which evaluates failures thresholds - so it should be possible to also implement original pattern using JCircuitBreaker.

Answer (score 0):

resilience4j is also a implementation of circuit breaker for java.

you can use 'circuit breaker', 'retry'.

guide: https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/circuitbreaker