# Kill a request taking too long in Java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, java-threads

I have a simple Java Servlet application running. It has a few endpoints. Although the service is pretty fast, there are a few requests that I get which sometimes take more time than expected. What will be the best way to kill any requests that take say more than ~20 secs to process?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to interrupt the request handling thread and you are using Tomcat you can try [Stuck Thread Detection Valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html#Stuck_Thread_Detection_Valve):

> **interruptThreadThreshold**
>
> Minimum duration in seconds after which a stuck thread should be interrupted to attempt to "free" it.
>
> Note that there's no guarantee that the thread will get unstuck. This usually works well for threads stuck on I/O or locks, but is probably useless in case of infinite loops.
>
> Default is -1 which disables the feature. To enable it, the value must be greater or equal to threshold.

It might be better to implement [Circuit Breaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30285637/circuit-breaker-design-pattern-implementation) in the client as `interruptThreadThreshold` is not guaranteed to work for all scenarios.

Comment: Hi Karol, thank you for your response. Unfortunately my service runs an embedded Jetty server and not Tomcat. However I came up with a workaround for this. I'm putting my code inside a timer task and handling the TimeoutException. Hopefully this should not use too much resources if task shutdown fails.